# Finding the rank of an element using modified quicksort

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find the rank of an element, defined as k where in an unsorted list, the rank would be the k^th lowest value in the list.

E.G.
Given a list:
[5,4,1,10,8,3,2]

Where k is 1, value is 1
Where k is 3, value is 3
Where k is 6, value is 8
Where k is 7, value is 10

I have to use a modified quicksort partition function provided below.

```
def partition(a_list, first, last):

    pivot = a_list[last]
    i = first - 1
    for j in range(first, last):
        if a_list[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            a_list[i], a_list[j] = a_list[j], a_list[i]

    a_list[i + 1], a_list[last] = a_list[last], a_list[i + 1]

    return i + 1
```

I'm looking for a function with an expected running time of O(n), I'm trying to recursively navigate through the list by calling partition and then deciding whether to go through the right half or left half, but I'm having trouble actually getting the results that are expected. Here is my selection method.

```
def selection(a_list, first, last, k):
    intReturn = partition(a_list, first, last)
    print(a_list)
    print(intReturn)
    if intReturn == k:
        return a_list[intReturn - 1]
    else:
        if intReturn < k:
            return selection(a_list, first + intReturn, last, k) #- (first + intReturn))
        elif intReturn > k:
            return a_list[k]
            #return selection(a_list, first, last - intReturn, k)
```

The selection function should be called as follows:

```
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 1))
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 3))
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 6))
print(selection([5,4,1,10,8,3,2], 0, 6, 7))
print(selection([46, 50, 16, 88, 79, 77, 17, 2, 43, 13, 86, 12, 68, 33, 81, \
74, 19, 52, 98, 70, 61, 71, 93, 5, 55], 0, 24, 19))
```

So yea, how do I go about recursively at expected running time O(n) to find an element given a certain rank without having to sort the whole list? While being restricted to this particular way of partitioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this? One observation that might help is that the partition function returns the index (starting from zero) of the pivot element.

```
def selection(a_list, first, last, k):
    assert (k - 1 >= first)
    assert (k - 1 <= last)
    intReturn = partition(a_list, first, last)

    if intReturn + 1 == k:
         return a_list[intReturn]

    if intReturn + 1 < k:
        return selection(a_list, intReturn + 1, last, k)

    if intReturn + 1 > k:
        return selection(a_list, first, intReturn - 1, k)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! While the other answer at first appeared more elaborate, it did not actually return the expected answer as provided.

I can see obviously now the error in logic I made when trying to split into the halves so this makes way more sense now!

Answer (score 1):

The Python cookbooks has at least two worked-out examples [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/269554-select-the-nth-smallest-element/) and [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/466330-fast-select/).

This is my version:

```
import random

def select(data, n):
    "Find the nth rank ordered element (the least value has rank 0)."
    data = list(data)
    if not 0 <= n < len(data):
        raise ValueError('not enough elements for the given rank')
    while True:
        pivot = random.choice(data)
        pcount = 0
        under, over = [], []
        uappend, oappend = under.append, over.append
        for elem in data:
            if elem < pivot:
                uappend(elem)
            elif elem > pivot:
                oappend(elem)
            else:
                pcount += 1
        if n < len(under):
            data = under
        elif n < len(under) + pcount:
            return pivot
        else:
            data = over
            n -= len(under) + pcount
```

As you requested, here is a recursive version of the same code:

```
def select(data, n):
    "Find the nth rank ordered element (the least value has rank 0)."
    if not 0 <= n < len(data):
        raise ValueError('not enough elements for the given rank')
    pivot = random.choice(data)
    pcount = 0
    under, over = [], []
    uappend, oappend = under.append, over.append
    for elem in data:
        if elem < pivot:
            uappend(elem)
        elif elem > pivot:
            oappend(elem)
        else:
            pcount += 1
    if n < len(under):
        return select(under, n)
    elif n < len(under) + pcount:
        return pivot
    else:
        return select(over, n - len(under) - pcount)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, avoiding quadratic runtime when the array is all the same element!